# SQL Server 2008 Express - Split Date and Time / Change Date / Concatenate New Date with Original Time

Tags: date, time, concatenation, sql-server-2008-express

I'm relatively new to SQL and need to do the following

- Split a Date and Time
- Change the Date
- Concatenate the New Date with Original Time

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated as Google searches haven't found me anything yet!

Thanks
Paul

Answer (score 2):

Just use the [`DATEADD`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) function if you want to change part of an existing DATETIME value.

> Returns a specified date with the specified number interval (signed integer) added to a specified datepart of that date.

For example, if you want to add a month to an existing day:

```
DATEADD(mm, 1, mydate)
```